# How to apply css to first n elements when hovering the nth element

Tags: html, css

This was an interview question I was asked from Amazon.
The question is to use HTML and css only to apply some css to the first n elements when hovering the nth element.
i.e.
You have 5 grey stars on the page, and when you hover the 4th star, the first 4 stars change to yellow, just like the rating UI on Amazon.

Comment: there is a lot of way to achieve this, we need more context as this is actually too broad ... but the duplicate will give you many workarounds

Comment: Basically you need to learn the use of the ~ CSS selector. Here's an example I made: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wEZNra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a flexbox with [`flex-direction: row-reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) and the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) `~`. The siblings selector will effect all siblings that come after the hovered the item, and the reversed flexbox will display them before the hovered item.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  list-style: none;
}

.container li:hover, .container li:hover ~ li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>X</li>
</ul>
```